# Getting schema info in mysql query

Tags: node.js, mysql2

I have a table in mysql database, which has three records. The table has 11 columns. I am using [mysql2](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2) for query;
my query is:

```
let mylist=[];
     mylist = await  pool.query( "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE username = ?", usrname);
```

Instead of getting an array of three objects, I get an array which has two arrays inside. In first array there are the three records I want to get.
But in second array I get results like below:

```
1: Array(11)
0:
characterSet: 63
columnLength: 8
columnType: 3
decimals: 0
encoding: "binary"
flags: 16903
name: "id"
_buf: {type: "Buffer", data: Array(886)}
_catalogLength: 3
_catalogStart: 10
_clientEncoding: "utf8"
_orgNameLength: 2
_orgNameStart: 37
_orgTableLength: 7
_orgTableStart: 26
_schemaLength: 3
_schemaStart: 14
_tableLength: 7
_tableStart: 18
__proto__: Object
1:
characterSet: 224
columnLength: 56
columnType: 253
decimals: 0
encoding: "utf8"
flags: 20485
name: "mnm"
_buf: {type: "Buffer", data: Array(886)}
_catalogLength: 3
_catalogStart: 57
_clientEncoding: "utf8"
_orgNameLength: 3
_orgNameStart: 85
_orgTableLength: 7
_orgTableStart: 73
_schemaLength: 3
_schemaStart: 61
_tableLength: 7
_tableStart: 65
__proto__: Object
2:
characterSet: 224
columnLength: 48
columnType: 253
decimals: 0
encoding: "utf8"
flags: 20489
etc...
etc....
```

I want to know the reason I am getting in my query results this second array object about details of all the columns which I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that it is a [issue](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/issues/648) with [node-mysql2](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2) . The work around is (as given in issue discussion) to query like

```
const [rows] = await conn.query(sql);
```

or like this

```
db.query(query).then(function(response) {
    var data = response[0];
    // use data
});
```